# Using check boxes to insert data into a database with a text box

Tags: sql, database, checkbox

I want to insert data selected from check boxes into a database as well as text which the user types into a text box. I want both the check box values and the text to go into the same row on my database.

My code for abc.php:

```
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Please select the answer below:</h2>
  <form>

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="response" value="A">A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="response" value="B">B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="response" value="C">C</label>
    </div>





<form method="post" name="input" action="insert.php" >
Question ID: <input name="questionid" type="text"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="insert" />
</form>
```

my code for insert.php

```
if(isset($_POST["response"]))
{


    $query = "INSERT INTO response (student_id, response, question_id) VALUES (:studentID, :response, :questionid)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
      array(
        ':response' => $_POST["response"],
        ':studentID' => $_SESSION['studentid'],
        ':questionid' => $_POST["questionid"]

      )
        );

}
```

When i press the insert button, nothing happens..... can anyone help?

Comment: is your php being fired or is the problem the $statement not saving to db?

Comment: Your HTML is wrong.  You have two <form> tags.  One for the checkbox (which is missing </form> by the way) and another one for the text area.  This should be only one <form>, containing both the checkboxes and text area.  Then your $_POST will contain both values, which you can then process and insert into the DB.

Comment: And your <form> for checkboxes does not have the input or action parameters either.